# php command to delete the file after running

Tags: php, delete-file

I have to run an installer written in php code that has to be deleted after it is run.  It is a run-once setup process that for security reasons needs to be removed so it cannot be run again.  The final lines of code  display that the routine successfully completed then exits.
Is there a way to script in for he file to "self destruct" after displaying that message?

It has never failed a successful run so I am not very worried about having to add another copy of it if that should ever happen.

Answer (score 4):

all you need do is add

```
unlink(__FILE__);
```

to the end